# How do you create a generic method in Java where one of the parameterized types must implement Iterable?

Tags: java, generics

Here's the method I'm trying to write ( doesn't compile now, because `what` is not seen as an Iterable ):

```
public <T,V> ArrayList<V> mySelect(T what,ITest<V> x) {
     ArrayList<V> results = new ArrayList<V>();
     for(V value : what) {
        if(x.accept(value)) {
           results.add(value);
        }
     }  
     return results;
}
```

The `T` type implements `Iterable` , and returns `V` objects when using `foreach`. The thing is, I don't know how to write that. Can you help?

Comment: Unrelated, but your method should return an interface such as List. Also the standard Java naming convention for interfaces is to NOT prepend an "I" in front.

Comment: You may get some value using ITest<? super V> and/or Iterable<? extends V>. The method's code wouldn't have to change, but you would be able to pass in a broader range of ITests (such as an ITest<Object>).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public <T extends Iterable<V>,V> ArrayList<V> mySelect(T what, ITest<V> x) {
```

The logic behind: `T` is any subclass (implementing class in this case) of `Iterable`, and
the `Iterable` is defined to iterate on `V`

I would recommend reading araqnid's suggestion, because it shows you how to make your code clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to define T as a parameter type at all?

```
public <V> ArrayList<V> mySelect(Iterable<V> what, ITest<V> x) {
```

And it's usually good form to return the interface List rather than the implementation ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would have written it. I wouldn't return an ArrayList explictly as the caller should know or expect a specific collection type.

```
public <V> List<V> mySelect(Iterable<V> what,ITest<V> x) {
     List<V> results = new ArrayList<V>();
     for(V value : what) 
        if(x.accept(value)) results.add(value);
     return results;
}
```